# Error downloading Xcode on macOS

Tags: xcode, macos

When I go to the Apple app store and tried to download I got the below response, can I get any idea how I can bypass this issue?

> Xcode can’t be installed on “Macintosh HD” because macOS version
>   10.13.2 or later is required.

Comment: So, do you have macOS 10.13.2 or later?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like you have old OS X. Try to download from the internet Xcode 3/4/5.
[image]

https://www.appcoda.com/how-to-download-older-version-of-xcode/
Read this about older versions.

To check your OS X:

1. Go to the left top part of the screen.

[image]

2. Press "About This Mac". Now you see your OS X and can Google for suitable xCode version.
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

You are probably running Sierra or less, You need to update you Mac OS X into High Sierra in order to update and use the latest Xcode 9.3.

**Note:** You could be running High Sierra but make sure you update to the latest OS X Release from App Store > Updates Tap and make sure its all updated.

Comment: He can also download an old version of Xcode from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/  That is of course a terrible idea in this case.  But someone may hit this thread with a valid need.